# How to query json with python UDF or json_extract in BigQuery?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure.

1. if total_order_items_quantity = 1,

```
  "user_id": "694520",
  "event_properties": {
    "item_brand": "P.A.M.",
    "item_color": "CAROLINA BLUE",
    "item_discount_price": "45000",
    "item_discount_rate": "0",
    "item_gender": "M",
    "item_id": "137194",
    "item_name": "A+ SS TEE",
    "item_price": "45000",
    "item_size": "XL",
    "total_order_items_quantity": 1
```

2. if total_order_items_quantity >= 2,

```
 "user_id": "694520",
 "event_properties": {
    "item_brand": [
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE"
    ],
    "item_color": [
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH"
    ],
    "item_discount_price": [
      88960,
      88960,
      88960,
      88960,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360
    ],
    "item_discount_rate": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "item_gender": [
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U"
    ],
    "item_id": [
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028"
    ],
    "item_name": [
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS"
    ],
    "item_price": [
      111200,
      111200,
      111200,
      111200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200
    ],
    "item_size": [
      "285",
      "285",
      "290",
      "290",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230"
    ],
    "total_order_items_quantity": 9
  }
```

Final output to aim for

```
| user_id | item brand | item_discount_price | item_discount_rate|
| 0001    | 1          |  1111               | 1                 |
| 0001    | 1          |  2222               | 1                 |
| 0001    | 1          |  3333               | 1                 |
```

But I don't know how to query.

I tried unnest(json_extract_array) like

```
  unnest(json_extract_array(event_properties,'$.item_brand'))
```

But Since the parameter type exists at the same time as an array and a value, Doesn't seem to be querying properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the data should be as an ARRAY of STRUCTS (rather than a struct OR ARRAYs of each item) each containing the `item_brand`, `item_price`, `item_discounted_price` etc. That way the querying is more natural w/ sql.

You could use another way to first transform the data into an Array of structs to be consistent but one way to doing this with SQL is to use `CASE` `WHEN` statements and transform the data into an array of structs.

Here's an example of what you could do with the JSON type.
It uses the case/when statements to check the `total_order_items_quantity` and then creates a uniform Array or structs which is stored in data.

When the data is singular you can simple create an array with a single value
i.e

```
ARRAY(
        SELECT STRUCT(JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_brand) AS item_brandz,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_color) AS item_colorz,
...                                            JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_id) AS item_idz))
```

When the data is an ARRAY it has to employ the `UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_brand))` on each of the array items such as the following:

```
ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      item_brandz, item_colorz, item_discount_pricez, item_discount_ratez, item_idz, item_namez
    FROM
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_brand)) as item_brandz, 
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_color)) as item_colorz, 
...
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_id)) as item_idz)
```

I've only filled in some properties here rather than all the values.

Here's the entire query with the JSON type. It flattens the entire data and hopefully gives you what you expect.

```
WITH
  t AS (
  SELECT
    JSON '''{"user_id": "694520", 
    "event_properties": {"item_brand": "P.A.M.",
    "item_color": "CAROLINA BLUE",
    "item_discount_price": "45000",
    "item_discount_rate": "0",
    "item_gender": "M",
    "item_id": "137194",
    "item_name": "A+ SS TEE",
    "item_price": "45000",
    "item_size": "XL",
    "total_order_items_quantity": 1}}''' AS payload
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    JSON '''{"user_id": "694520",
 "event_properties": {
    "item_brand": [
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE",
      "NIKE"
    ],
    "item_color": [
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "BAROQUE BROWN VELVET BROWN BAROQUE BROWN",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH",
      "FLASH/WHITE-ARGON BLUE-FLASH"
    ],
    "item_discount_price": [
      88960,
      88960,
      88960,
      88960,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360,
      95360
    ],
    "item_discount_rate": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "item_gender": [
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U",
      "U"
    ],
    "item_id": [
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "140312",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028",
      "141028"
    ],
    "item_name": [
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO PRM",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS",
      "DUNK LOW RETRO QS"
    ],
    "item_price": [
      111200,
      111200,
      111200,
      111200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200,
      119200
    ],
    "item_size": [
      "285",
      "285",
      "290",
      "290",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230",
      "230"
    ],
    "total_order_items_quantity": 9
  }}''' AS payload ),
  DATA AS (
  SELECT
    payload.user_id as user_idz,
    INT64(payload.event_properties.total_order_items_quantity) AS x,
    CASE
      WHEN INT64(payload.event_properties.total_order_items_quantity) = 1 THEN ARRAY(
        SELECT STRUCT(JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_brand) AS item_brandz,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_color) AS item_colorz,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_discount_price) AS item_discount_pricez,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_discount_rate) AS item_discount_ratez,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_name) AS item_namez,
                      JSON_VALUE(payload.event_properties.item_id) AS item_idz))
      WHEN INT64(payload.event_properties.total_order_items_quantity) > 1 THEN ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT
      item_brandz, item_colorz, item_discount_pricez, item_discount_ratez, item_idz, item_namez
    FROM
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_brand)) as item_brandz, 
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_color)) as item_colorz, 
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_discount_price)) as item_discount_pricez,
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_discount_rate)) as item_discount_ratez,
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_name)) as item_namez,
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(payload.event_properties.item_id)) as item_idz)
  END
    AS item_properties
  FROM
    t)
SELECT
  user_idz,
  props.item_brandz, props.item_colorz, props.item_discount_pricez, props.item_idz, props.item_namez,
FROM
  DATA, UNNEST(item_properties) as props;
```